# Как установить x64bit гостевую систему в VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vagrant

Недоступны x64 системы в VirtualBox (5.1.10), образы с x32 работают

Основная система Win 8.1, Hyper-V не установлен

Процессор [INTEL Core i5 3570](http://ark.intel.com/ru/products/65702/Intel-Core-i5-3570-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz), виртуализацию поддерживает

В списке настроек VM есть только x32 системы, x64 cиcтемы отсутствую.

Есть идеи, что можно сделать? Пробовал поставить версию VB 5.0.30 - то же самое.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Зайдите в байос - там надо выставить явную поддержку виртуализации. После этого все должно работать.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019231/vt-not-supported-when-installing-haxm

Comment: Да, действительно, всё было просто.

Answer (score 1):

У меня была подобная проблема, решилась включением опции VT-d в BIOS